# .gitignore with Visual Studio Solutions containing multiple project folders

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitignore, projects-and-solutions

I have a c:\git folder where I store all my code.
In this folder is a folder for each application/solution.
Each application/solution can have many projects.

Example folder structure:

```
c:\git\abc\abc-da\
c:\git\abc\abc-WebUI\
c:\git\abc\abc-WinService\
c:\git\abc\abc-Tester\
c:\git\abc\abc-UnitTest\
```

My question is this:
If I put my VisualStudio.gitIgnore file in the c:\git\abc\ folder (named .gitignore obviously) then would it apply to all subfolders? or do I have to copy the .gitignore to each project folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.gitignore` applies to a project from the root, and matches children via the glob search. Additionally, any `.gitignore` files in children directories from the root of a project, will apply the same. This stops once you hit a `.git` directory (the indicator for the start of a repo).

Separately from that, you can set a global `.gitignore` file that Git will apply to *all* projects under a particular git installation (or, installations referencing that file).

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore
```

Usually this goes in your home folder as `~/.gitignore` or `~/.gitignore_global` and is used to ignore files related to your personal setup (ie, you use IntelliJ? Ignore `.idea`, don't ignore it on *every* project).

Beyond that, I do not believe Git has additional builtin functionality for `.gitignore`.

Fantastic references:

- https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore
- https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give that a try!